# How to run a Next.js project on a specific port?

Tags: ubuntu, next.js, devops, port, forever

Here is the content of `server.js` file:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const next = require("next");

const dev = false;
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();

    // requests to /service-worker.js
    server.get(
      "/service-worker.js",
      express.static(path.join(__dirname, ".next"))
    );

    // all other requests
    server.get("*", (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });
    server.listen(3002, (err) => {                            // this
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:3002");        // this
    });
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

As I've highlighted, I'm running the project on port `3002`. But after running `forever start server.js`, still `http://<ip>:3002` is not reachable.

Also, when I run `yarn start` on the root of the project, it says:

> Port 3000 is already in use.

[image]

Why it doesn't care about the port I specified inside `server.js` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I've highlighted, I'm running the project on port 3002

That's not what you did, you just made your server listening on PORT 3002 but when you run `yarn start` the project will start on the default port 3000

you can change it this way in your `package.json` file:

```json
"scripts": {
//...
"dev": "next dev -p 3002",
"start": "next start -p 3002",
},
```

You also need to check if the port itself is listening on the server(`lsof | grep -i PORT`) and then enable access on the firewall, use the following command to enable access in the firewall:
`sudo ufw allow 3002/tcp`

Just make sure [ufw](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorial_collections/ufw-firewall-setup) is installed & properly setup.

Comment: Thanks, but it stucks on this https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT84e.png

Comment: try to run next run dev on port 3003 before it

Comment: also clean the cache under dev tools / application

Comment: any command for clearing the cache ? I'm just rebuilding `yarn build`

Comment: @MartinAJ, you just need to run `yarn dev -p 3003` to get it working. I should clarify that's if you want to run on port 3003 in dev mode, otherwise, you would need to build the website with `yarn run build` first & then run `yarn start -p 3003`. The website isn't stuck, it's just waiting for you to visit the website to serve, in other words, it's listening for incoming requests, that's why it looks like it's hanging.

Comment: Not working https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNXoF.png .. Probably I need to define something inside Nginx config file about port 3002

Comment: @MartinAJ, No it's working perfectly, you must make sure the PORT itself is accessible on the server itself. In other words, make sure the PORT is allowed incoming requests, check the firewall settings.

Comment: You mean this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRGz9.png

Comment: Exactly, but this just shows that there is an open service with the respective ports, it doesn't show whether it's allowed access from the outside(the internet). You can try to allow the port on the firewall setting.

Comment: Depending on the linux os you're running you could try to run or install UFW, then all the specific port this way, `sudo ufw allow 3003/tcp`

Comment: oh .. very good buddy, worked, thx

Comment: does not work on http://127.0.0.1:3002 ?

Comment: It's working here `http://37.152.179.101:3002/`

Comment: You're welcome, I am going to add the instructions in an answer to help future people, mark it as an answer. This comment section got destroyed, haha.